# LFS can't cd to lfs/source - permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, lfs

I'm trying to build a LFS using version 7.1. I've followed all of the steps up to 5.3 and now I'm stuck because I can't change to $LFS/sources - I get the message:

```
bash: cd: /mnt/lfs/sources: Permission denied
```

I'm logged in, in a new terminal, as lfs. The directory permissions (as seen from /mnt/lfs by root) are:

```
drwx------ 6 leo  leo   4096 May 26 18:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 May 21 20:43 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 May 21 20:24 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 leo  leo   4096 May 26 18:00 patches
drwxrwxrwt 2 lfs  root  4096 May 26 17:53 sources
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfs  root  4096 May 26 18:02 tools
```

The mount spec for the partition is:

```
/dev/sdb3 on /mnt/lfs type ext3 (rw)
```

I'm far from new to UNIX and LINUX and this is really annoying me. I know it's something blindingly obvious but I just can't see it.

I have restarted the machine, sourced the lfs profile (source ~/.bash_profile) but just can't seem to find the one thing I'm missing. The host system is Debian if that helps.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /mnt/` and `ls -ld /`

Comment: 'drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 21 20:43 /mnt/' and 'drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 May 26 18:02 /'

Comment: I don't know LFS but it seems it is using a dedicated user for building the software and `/mnt/lfs` has some pretty restrictive permissions. `chmod 755 /mnt/lfs` should probably solve your issue

Answer (score 4):

You `/mnt/lfs` directory is restricted to user `leo` (mode `0700`), no-one else can enter it.

Change that to `755` (`chmod go+rx /mnt/lfs`) and things should work out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried those suggestions but to no avail. I recalled that I created the user lfs, then deleted it and recreated it *after* assigning owner permissions. So I completely deleted it (and associated files) again, reassigned ownership to root and went through the whole process again.

Still, I couldn't change into `/mnt/lfs/sources` or `/mnt/lfs/tools`. So I tried changing `/mnt/lfs` to `755` again and it all worked. Weird - I should be able to enter a child directory to which I have granted access even though I don't have access to the parent.

Comment: "I should be able to enter a child directory to which I have granted access even though I don't have access to the parent." No, you shouldn't. You need x permissions from `/` to the final directory.

Comment: Surely that would imply that any user could change to any higher up directory in the filesystem.

Comment: See [chdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) in POSIX: "`EACCESS` Search permission is denied for any component of the pathname." - note that the check is done at the time of call. You could change permissions on a path component afterwards (which would very likely have strange effects on unsuspecting processes).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

```
root@host--$: chmod 777 -R /mnt/lfs
root@host--$: chmod 777 -R /mnt/lfs/sources
root@host--$: chmod 777 -R /mnt/lfs/tools
```

It will solve your issue.